# The "dataProvider" property must be set

Tags: php, веб-программирование, yii2

Работаю с yii2 advanced

Хочу направить 2 значения в представление view. Это написано в экшене контроллера:

```
return $this->render('index', array('message'=>$message, 'smLaTi'=>$smLaTi));
```

При запуске появляется ошибка:
The "dataProvider" property must be set.

Comment: Видимо, используется в шаблоне GridView и не указан dataProvider

Comment: Нет, хочу принимать его в "index" без использования widget'a

Comment: Во view `index` точно нет `ListView` или `GridView`, у который не указано свойство `dataProvider`?

Comment: Да, я понял свою ошибку.
Если простым языком, то отправляя свойства в render нужно убедиться, что закрываешь данными все "приемщики данных" в самом представлении.
В моем случае, я отправлял эти две переменные позабыв о том, что на странице есть GridView и он требует dataProvider